# Why $_POST is removing HTML tags from string?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, fat-free-framework

I'm on PHP 5.6 using the Fat Free Framework (if it matters) and having a weird issue. I am sending form data to the server like so:

```
function submitForm(form) 
{
    var fd = new FormData();
    var file_data = isImageIncluded ? $('input[type="file"]')[0].files : [];
    for (var i = 0; i < file_data.length; i++) {
        fd.append("file_" + i, file_data[i]);
    }
    var other_data = $(form).serializeArray();
    $.each(other_data, function(key, input) {
        fd.append(input.name, input.value);
    });

    sendData(url, fd, form);
}

function sendData(url, data, form) 
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
});
```

}

So as I debug the code above, I see the data being sent from the wysiwyg with html tags like `<b></b>`.

The problem is on the PHP side. Here's the method:

```
public function editRelease()
{
    var_dump($_POST['description']);exit;
}
```

And cannot get the description to show the html tags in the string. Does anyone have an idea on what's happening?

### EDIT

Here's a screenshot of my headers from Chrome. I marked the object I'm referring to. As it shows, the html tags are going to the server, so I'm not sure why it's not showing in the $_POST array.

[image: screenshot]

### EDIT 2

And here is a screenshot of the response I get corresponding to the screenshot of the headers above:
[image]

Has anyone ever seen this?

Comment: just to be sure, if you output the string like that in a html context, you'd not see `<b></b>`, but rather the text bold. `echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['description']);`? have you checked in your console that the correct data is sent to your page?

Comment: Yes, I've checked to see what is being sent. The headers show all the tags, whether bold, italic, strikethrough, etc. It's only the response that wipes them. I will try the htmlspecialchars method. Thanks!

Comment: there is other code at work which you are not showing us

Comment: Ok I will post the full js and php methods

Comment: @Dagon I edited with the full code.

Comment: I don't know php but asp.net has a anti scipt injection, that requires strings with '<' and '>' to be double  encoded. You could try that and manually decode on server.

Comment: Any special reason why you doing `contentType: false,
        processData: false,` ?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Because I'm sending files in other forms as well. I created a catch-all function for about 5 forms.

Comment: if you are using fat-free-framework, why would you not use `$f3->get('REQUEST.description');` or `$f3->get('POST.description');`?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst:contentType: false, processData: false is necessary with JQuery when using FormData !

Comment: @Daniel This is my first time using the framework. Thanks for the heads up. Would that be a clue as to what's happening?

Comment: probably not, you could try anyway. How do you know it's not showing up?  I am wondering if there is a php.ini setting or something about the environment that is causing this, but I don't know of a php setting that would remove the tags

Comment: @Daniel Thanks. I tried it but nothing. I know it's not showing in two ways: 1) it's not showing in the database when I save and 2) I've commented all the unnecessary things out and simply ```echo $_POST[description]``` and all the tags are not there, even though they are sent.

Comment: I can tell you that I do have code that uses post to pass wysiwyg editor content, and I haven't had the issue. Any chance it's being removed as a result of some other operation? did you try print_r/var_dump on _POST with a die after and viewing the result of that?

Comment: what about url encoding the string before it is sent?

Comment: @Daniel I'm sending everything as form data. And to your previous point, I have a project similar to this that works fine as well. The only key differences for me are the php version and framework used.

Comment: @Pang Sorry, editRelease. No typos in the code. I copied and pasted.

Comment: Why is it so hard to post **minimal code** to demonstrate the issue? People always dump their entire project here.

Comment: @bytecode77 I posted minimal code first and someone above complained. To simplify it here, I'm sending form data with html inside and the html is not saving in my database.

Comment: @bytecode77 I stripped down everything again. Have you ever seen this problem? I wish people wouldn't downvote. I'm really trying to understand what's happening.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it, but I can't. Maybe this has something to do with your JavaScript? Try debugging the JS variables step by step and see if they "lose" their HTML tags anywhere.

Comment: @bytecode77 I appreciate that. I've been doing it for hours. The thing is, if you take a look at the header screenshot above, the tags are there. I don't know what else to search for between the headers being sent and ```echo $_POST[description]``` happening. As I said above, this is the first I'm seeing it, but I'm also using a different framework and developing on PHP 5.6. I've even stripped this thing down to blatantly posting a hardcoded object with tags and still getting the same result.

Comment: Maybe it's a PHP configuration, a framework or something else. Try this: http://pastebin.com/r8vSQfRE - does it cause the same issue?

Comment: @bytecode77 Thank you! You helped me at least narrow it down. So the test was fine. I was able to see ```<b></b>``` tags from my input in the devtools Networking tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those wondering, I found out that in my variation of the Fat Free Framework, called [F3 Boilerplate](https://github.com/vijinho/f3-boilerplate), there was a section of code stripping the tags out. Inside of its app.php, I found

```
// clean ALL incoming user input by default
$request = array();
foreach (array('GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'COOKIE') as $var) {
    $input = $f3->get($var);
    if (is_array($input) && count($input)) {
        $cleaned = array();
        foreach ($input as $k => $v) {
            $k = strtolower(trim($f3->clean($k)));
            $v = $f3->clean($v);
            if (empty($v)) {
                continue;
            }
            $cleaned[$k] = $v;
            $request[$k] = $v;
        }
        ksort($cleaned);
        $f3->set($var, $cleaned);
    }
}
```

which removes tags from all incoming input using `$f3->clean()` so I had to modify it to whitelist tags as explained in the documentation http://fatfreeframework.com/base#clean.

Comment: This piece of code doesn't belong to the framework. It is part of your app.

Comment: I actually just realized that. I'm using a child framework (if you will) called F3 Boilerplate. It's an MVC version of Fat Free. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: well that explains it

Comment: Would be nice if you could update your answer then, just to be fair ;)